# How to create a master list comprised of elements of multiple lists in Python?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

What my code is supposed to do, is to run through a text file (which I've stored in a dict with `linenum` as the keys), and then search each line for a word from `Lwordli`. If the program finds the word, then loop through the different Lists stored in my `MasterLi` to identify if one or more other words in that sentence match up to what is in the lists. If it does, then do `condition`, if not, then move on to the `elif` condition and check another list, etc. Then do that for each sentence in `txt`.

I have multiple lists which i need to store inside 1 master for an if-else statement. I'm currently just trying something like this:

```
Li1 = []
Li2 = []

MasterLi = Li1, Li2

Lwordli = []
```

Then this  is an example of how it would need to run inside my code with some of my actual code which is throwing back an error, if anyone can think of a better way than four For loops, that would be helpful, but main focus is how to call individual lists from Master:

```
for key, value in Txt.items()
    for cword in MasterLi: #Outer List loop
       for lword in lwordli:
           for section in value:



           pattern = r'\b' + re.escape(lword) + r'\b.*\b' + re.escape(cword) + r'\b|\b' + re.escape(
                    cword) + r'\b.*' + re.escape(lword) + r'\b'

           if re.search(pattern, section, re.I | re.M):

               if cword in Li1:

                   # Do condition


               elif cword in Li2:

                    # Do condition etc.
```

Traceback  Error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Lewis Collins/PycharmProjects/Test/main.py", line 134, in <module>
    languagemodel()
  File "C:/Users/Lewis Collins/PycharmProjects/Test/main.py", line 94, in languagemodel
    cword) + r'\b.*' + re.escape(lword) + r'\b'
  File "C:\Users\Lewis Collins\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\re.py", line 267, in escape
    return bytes(s)
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

I believe this error is caused by how I'm trying to store lists inside a Master list to be called as my code works perfect if i attempt to do for loop as:

```
for word in Li1:
```

Comment: Please fix your syntax errors and your code indentation, it is not For but `for`!

Comment: @ettanany fixed

Comment: You need to be more clear about what you want. Add some examples of inputs and the output that you expect.

Answer (score 3):

To create a master list that contains elements of all the lists, you can use the `+` operator, i.e.`MasterLi = Li1 + Li2`. You can also achieve this by using the`extend` method of lists.
Your current approach is creating a tuple of lists, which does not seem to be what you need.

Comment: brilliant my code now works smoothly thanks so much can't believe all i was missing was "+" operator

Comment: @L.C Glad to be of help.

Answer (score 1):

Actually your error message points at a problem in the call to `re.escape()`, which could triggered by either `cword` or `lword`. I suggest you rewrite this part:

```
pattern = r'\b' + re.escape(lword) + r'\b.*\b' + re.escape(cword) + r'\b|\b' + re.escape(
                cword) + r'\b.*' + re.escape(lword) + r'\b'
```

as:

```
try:
    lword_escaped = re.escape(lword)
except TypeError as e:
    print("re.escape failed with on lword '{}'".format(lword)
    raise
try:
    cword_escaped = re.escape(cword)
except TypeError as e:
    print("re.escape failed with on cword '{}'".format(cword)
    raise

pattern = (
    r'\b' + lword_escaped + r'\b.*\b' + cword_escaped 
    + r'\b|\b' + cword_escaped + r'\b.*' + lword_escaped + r'\b'
    )
```

This wont fix the problem by itself but at least you'll know what exactly triggers the error.

Also, if by "master list" you mean a concatenation of two lists, this is spelled `master_list = list1 + list2`. What you get with `MasterLi = Li1, Li2` is a `tuple` of two list.

Finally, if all you want is to test if a given word belongs to a given list and branch according on which list the word came from, there are better options. Assuming your `Li1` and `Li2` lists don't change during the loop, you'd be better using an iterator taking (, ) pairs and yielding `(<identifier>,`word`) tuples, ie:

```
def chain(*args):
    for identifier, lst in *args:
        for word in lst:
            yield identifier, word
```

and then replace `for cword in MasterLi` with:

```
for identifier, cword in chain(("l1", Li1), ("l2", Li2)):
    # various stuff here
    if identifier == "l1":
        # some processing here
    elif identifier == "l2":
        # some different processing here
```

etc. This will be **much** more time and space efficient (no need to build a huge "master list", no useless O(n) lookups to find out which list a given word comes from).

or you could just encapsulate the "# some processing here" and "# some different processing here" in functions and chain on `(<list>, <function>)` pairs, ie:

```
def handleLi1(...):
    # some processing here

def handleLi2(...):
    # some different processing here


def chain(*args):
    for lst, func in *args:
        for word in lst:
            yield word, func


for cword, func in chain((Li1, handleLi1), (Li2, handleLi2)):
    # various stuff here
    whatever = func(cword, whatever, arg, needed)
```

You just need to make sure both "handler" functions take the same args (and return the same kind of value if they have to return something)